# How to create java array of objects from SAS Base javaobj statement?

Tags: sas

I faced with trouble in declaring Java objects from SAS.
There is no way to set as parameter array of Java objects, or create object of array.

```
data _NULL_;
/*With primitive types work well     */
  declare javaobj jArr("java.util.Arrays");
  array primeNum{3} (15, 2, 3);
  jArr_rc1=jArr.callStaticVoidMethod("sort", primeNum);

/* For example, try to create array from some javaobjs   */
  declare javaobj num1("java.lang.Integer","15");
  declare javaobj num2("java.lang.Integer","2");
  declare javaobj num3("java.lang.Integer","3");
  array Num{3} (num1,num2,num3);
/* ERROR: Cannot create an array of objects. */
/* ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the COMPILATION phase. */

/*In my project I've tried different ways:   */
/*     ...callStaticVoidMethod("FuncFromStandartClass",[num1,num2,num3]); */
/*     ...callStaticVoidMethod("FuncFromStandartClass",{num1,num2,num3}); */

/* This code also didn't work*/
/*declare javaobj numArr("java.lang.Integer[]","3","4");*/
run;
```

I understand, that in particular cases I must create Java wrapper code, that will be pass through API only primitives.
But it's not always possible. And write code-wrapper for all classes in Java that you need is not effective.

Comment: Not a SAS developer, but I'm trying to understand how that language works. What does that $20 mean here "array s{3} $20 ("abc", "def", "ghi");" ?

Comment: @LppEdd `$20` means that array elements are character and average length of an element is 20.

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak thanks Igor. This language reminds me a bit of RPG/Cobol

Comment: Did you try making a hash of the java objects instead? I know you can make a hash of hash objects.

Comment: Did you try using PROC DS2 instead of plain DATA step?

Comment: The reason why I need array of java objects is that sometimes , in java there is an arrays of objects. So now  in this case I have to write my own Java class, that can understand/parse what sas push into method.

Comment: @Tom, I didn't find info about ability to call java methods from sas. If I missed some, please , correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaObj is not a general bridge into dynamic Java coding.  It is bridge to either very simple Java classes with SAS suitable method signatures, or more realistically a bridge to a well defined adapter class built for a specific role.

The `HASH` object can likely be used to maintain a collection `JavaObj` references, but that is getting into pretty deep water.

For general purpose java coding in SAS, look into `Proc GROOVY`.

There are quite a few conference papers regarding JavaObj, search them out.  If you are a coda-holic try 2005 [paper](https://www.devenezia.com/papers/sugi-30/241-30%20(JavaObj).pdf) "Java in SAS®: JavaObj, a DATA Step Component Object "

> The design of JavaObj creates many situations that require an adapter Java class to fully exploit the features of a library.

and [sample code](https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/macros/index.php?m=jdsgimac).

> Java DATA Step Graphics Interface - A combination of JavaObj accessible Java classes and SAS macros that let you can create almost any type of static 2D visualization

Now-a-days you might use HTML 5 canvas instead.

Comment: The main advantage of javaobj over proc groovy is that there is no need for the `XCMD` option to execute code. I've used `Hash` object in sas before, but never try to figure out how java will parse it. Thank you for links. The last one is amazing!

Comment: You may have seen some papers talking about 'hash of hashes'.  Because that works and a hash is component object (reference really) and a javaobj is a component object (reference really) seems likely a 'hash of javaobjs' probably works.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in SAS Base [can not](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi30/242-30.pdf) consist of Java object elements:

> All elements must be character or numeric.

Comment: well, yeah. that attempt was just a breakdown of the thought "what will happen if I write like that?". Thank you for you reply.